# Created simple HTML form with PHP, but won't POST email and opens blank page

Tags: php, html

I created the following HTML and PHP documents. When I fill in the information and click submit, I don't receive any errors, but I get a blank page and also don't receive an email with the form information. I'm fairly new at this, but could use the help on why I'm not getting the email and how to get rid of the blank page. Thank you.

```html
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<div id="title">
<div id="titlecontact">
<h1>Excelerate Growth, LLC</h1>
<h4><em>Consulting to Help Small Businesses Excel</em></h4>
</div>
</div>

<header id="header">
    <nav class="links" style="--items: 5;">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
        <a href="results.html">Results</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        <span class="line"></span>
    </nav>
</header>

<?=$thankYou ?>

<form class="form" action="contact2.php" method="POST">
<h1>CONTACT US</h1>
<p class="name">Name</p><input class="nametext" type="text" name="sender" />
<p class="email">Email</p><input class="emailtext" type="text" name="senderEmail" />
<p class="phone">Phone</p><input class="phonetext" type="tel" name="senderPhone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required />
<br />
<br />
<p class="interest">Interest</p>
<select class="package" name="type" size="1">
<option value="update">Free Consultation</option>
<option value="change">Growth Management</option>
<option value="addition">Customer Service</option>
<option value="new">Process Management</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<p class="message">Share More About Your Business</p><textarea class="text" name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br /><br />
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send"><input class="reset" type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>

<div id="social">
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/excelerate-growth/" target="_blank"><img class="linkedin" src="linkedin.png"></a>
<a href="mailto:excelerategrowth@gmail.com" target="_blank"><img class="email2" src="email.png"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/ExcelerateGrowthLLC/" target="_blank"><img class="facebook" src="facebook.png"></a>
<br/>
<br/>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
```

```js
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="jscotty78@gmail.com";
    $subject="Form to email message";
    $sender=$_POST["sender"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
    $senderPhone=$_POST["senderPhone"];
    $type=$_POST["type"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\nPhone: $senderPhone\nType: $type\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

      
?>
```

Comment: Try testing the return value of mail(). If it's `false`, then the e-mail delivery failed.

Comment: You might want to replace the social media buttons with placeholder images because they break in the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code Below with name="submit"

```
    <form class="form" action="contact2.php" method="POST">
        <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
        <p class="name">Name</p><input class="nametext" type="text" name="sender" />
    <p class="email">Email</p><input class="emailtext" type="text" name="senderEmail" />
    <p class="phone">Phone</p><input class="phonetext" type="tel" name="senderPhone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p class="interest">Interest</p>
    <select class="package" name="type" size="1">
    <option value="update">Free Consultation</option>
    <option value="change">Growth Management</option>
    <option value="addition">Customer Service</option>
    <option value="new">Process Management</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p class="message">Share More About Your Business</p><textarea class="text" name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br /><br />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"><input class="reset" type="reset" value="Clear">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

POST form data is sent using name => value. Here:

```html
<form class="form" action="contact2.php" method="POST">
<h1>CONTACT US</h1>
<p class="name">Name</p><input class="nametext" type="text" name="sender" />
<p class="email">Email</p><input class="emailtext" type="text" name="senderEmail" />
<p class="phone">Phone</p><input class="phonetext" type="tel" name="senderPhone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required />
<br />
<br />
<p class="interest">Interest</p>
<select class="package" name="type" size="1">
<option value="update">Free Consultation</option>
<option value="change">Growth Management</option>
<option value="addition">Customer Service</option>
<option value="new">Process Management</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<p class="message">Share More About Your Business</p><textarea class="text" name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br /><br />
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send"><input class="reset" type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

you have no input with name="submit". This is why $_POST['submit'] is equal to "", which is considered false in PHP. So mail() is not running.

Instead, try this:

```html
<form class="form" action="contact2.php" method="POST">
<h1>CONTACT US</h1>
<p class="name">Name</p><input class="nametext" type="text" name="sender" />
<p class="email">Email</p><input class="emailtext" type="text" name="senderEmail" />
<p class="phone">Phone</p><input class="phonetext" type="tel" name="senderPhone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required />
<br />
<br />
<p class="interest">Interest</p>
<select class="package" name="type" size="1">
<option value="update">Free Consultation</option>
<option value="change">Growth Management</option>
<option value="addition">Customer Service</option>
<option value="new">Process Management</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<p class="message">Share More About Your Business</p><textarea class="text" name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br /><br />
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send"><input class="reset" type="reset" value="Clear">
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="a" />
</form>
```

Notice name="submit". This gets sent along with the form data.

Comment: Or just add `name="submit"` to the submit button, rather than create a hidden input.

Comment: @David: Thanks, I didn't know I could do that!

Comment: Someone_who_likes_SE and @David. Thank you for the suggestions. I believe it worked. Now to get my server/host to allow the email to go through. after getting the following error: 
Warning: mail() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/vhosts/excelerategrowth.orgfree.com/contact2.php on line 14

Comment: @JasonSnyder: Then `mail()` has been disabled.  Contact your hosting provider for alternatives.  If they don't have anything available, you may need to use a 3rd party service.

Comment: @JasonSnyder Test the return value of mail(). If it returns `false`, then the e-mail host refused to send the mail. Otherwise, it's not your fault if e-mail delivery fails.